# Bootstrap isn't working fully in vite react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5, vite

I am a newbie in react & vite . So working on a vite react app which needs bootstrap. I've followed [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/vite/) on official bootstrap site. But all the bootstrap functionality dosen't seem to work. Like the button is working correctly but the forms aren't. Here is my project structure:

```
my-project/
|── node_modules
├── src/
│   ├── js/
│   │   └── main.js
│   └── scss/
│   |   └── styles.scss
|   └── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── vite.config.js
```

This is my main.js:

```
// Import our custom CSS
import "../scss/styles.scss";

// Import all of Bootstrap's JS
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";
```

This is styles.scss:

```
// Import all of Bootstrap's CSS
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

This is index.html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap w/ Vite</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Notifications <span class="badge badge-light">4</span>
    </button>
    <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And lastly this is vite.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

export default {
  root: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "~bootstrap": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/bootstrap"),
    },
  },
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

This is package.json :

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.61.0",
    "vite": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3"
  }
}
```

In the index.html the output should look like this:
[image: Badge]
But in my project it is looking like this:
[image: my Badge]

**Edit**
I downgraded my bootstrap version to 4.1.3. but the forms doesn't seem to work. Here is my result:
[image: form result]
Here is expected result:
[image: expected result]
Here is the latest package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.61.0",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The button you're expecting is from Bootstrap v4. But you have installed  Bootstrap v5 and it seems like working.

You should follow either Bootstrap v5 documentation; https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/badge/#examples

Or you can change your Bootstrap version.

Comment: I changed to bootstrap4.1.3 but the forms dosen't seem to work.  So I updated the question, Please have a look.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't provide auto paddings which is better you can add `body {padding: 1.5rem;}` in the styles.scss file or any padding you like